# Seeking open source equivalent to .mpk?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, open-source-gis, map-package

Is there an open source equivalent to the .mpk file format that ArcGIS can still open?

Comment: Perhaps GeoPackage.

Comment: What software are you wanting to use to try and write such an open source map package?